# Lex & Yacc AST homework

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, yacc

I need to write this function in AST, preorder, but when I run my yacc file, it prints "Segmentatio fault(core dumped)". If you can please help me resolve my problem, because it as been a few days and I still do not understand what to do. I checked my syntax and it is working, but for some reason when I add mknode and printtree to it, it prints this message. Please help me.

```
void foo(int x, y, z; real f){
if (x>y) {
x = x + f;
}
else {
y = x + y + z;
x = f*2;
z = f;
}
```

This is my yacc file, including my function printtree and mknode.

```
    %{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct node{
    char *token;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}node;
node *mknode(char *token, node *left, node *right);
void printtree(node *tree);
%}
%union
{ 
    char *s;
    struct node *node;
}
%token  IF ELSE INT CHAR VOID REAL RETURN GUI 
%left '*' 
%left '+'
%token <s> NUM ID FUNC 
%type <node> S start function func args args1 body if_st ret_st expr block ass calc
%type <s> type
%%

S: start {printtree($1);};
start: function {$$ = mknode("CODE",$1,NULL);};
function: func { $$ = mknode("FUNC",$1, NULL); };
func: type ID '(' args ')' '{' body '}' {$$ = mknode($2,NULL, mknode("ARGS", $4,mknode($1, NULL,$7)));};
type: INT {$$ = "INT";} 
     | CHAR {$$ = "CHAR";}
     | VOID {$$ = "VOID";}
     | REAL {$$ = "REAL";};
args: type args1 args {$$ = mknode($1,$2,$3);} | type args1 {$$ = mknode($1,$2,NULL);}  ;
args1: ID {$$ = mknode($1,NULL,NULL);}
     | ID ';' {$$ = mknode($1,NULL,NULL);}
     | ID ',' args1 {$$ = mknode($1,NULL,$3);}
     | { $$ = NULL; };  
body: if_st {$$ = mknode("BODY", $1, NULL);}  
    | ret_st {$$ = mknode("BODY", $1, NULL);};
if_st: IF'(' expr ')' '{'block'}' ELSE '{'block'}' {$$ = mknode("IF-ELSE",mknode(NULL,$3,mknode(NULL,$6,$10)),NULL);}
     | IF '(' expr ')' '{'block'}'{$$ = mknode("IF",$3,$6);} ;
expr: ID '<' ID {$$ = mknode("<",mknode($1,NULL,NULL),mknode($3,NULL,NULL));}
    | ID '>' ID {$$ = mknode(">",mknode($1,NULL,NULL),mknode($3,NULL,NULL));}
    | ID '=' ID  {$$ = mknode("==",mknode($1,NULL,NULL),mknode($3,NULL,NULL));}
    | ID '<' NUM {$$ = mknode("<",mknode($1,NULL,NULL),mknode($3,NULL,NULL));}
    | ID '>' NUM {$$ = mknode(">",mknode($1,NULL,NULL),mknode($3,NULL,NULL));}
    | ID '=' NUM  {$$ = mknode("==",mknode($1,NULL,NULL),mknode($3,NULL,NULL));};
block: block ass {$$ = mknode(NULL,$1,$2);}
     | ass {$$ = mknode(NULL,$1,NULL);};
ass: ID '=' calc ';'{$$ = mknode("=",mknode($1,NULL,NULL),mknode(NULL,$3,NULL));};
calc: ID '+' calc {$$ = mknode("+",mknode($1,NULL,NULL),mknode(NULL,$3,NULL));}
    | ID '*' calc {$$ = mknode("*",mknode($1,NULL,NULL),mknode(NULL,$3,NULL));}
    | NUM '+' calc {$$ = mknode("+",mknode($1,NULL,NULL),mknode(NULL,$3,NULL));}
    | NUM '*' calc {$$ = mknode("*",mknode($1,NULL,NULL),mknode(NULL,$3,NULL));}
    | NUM  {$$ = mknode($1,NULL,NULL);}
    | ID  {$$ = mknode($1,NULL,NULL);}; 
ret_st: RETURN  GUI calc GUI ';' { $$ = mknode("RET", $3, NULL); };
%%
#include "lex.yy.c"
int main()
{
    return yyparse();
}
node *mknode(char *token,node *left,node *right)
{
    node *newnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    char *newstr = (char*)malloc(sizeof*(token)+1);
    strcpy(newstr,token);
    newnode->left = left;
    newnode->right = right;
    newnode->token = newstr;
    return newnode; 
}
void printtree(node *tree)
{
    printf("%s\n",tree->token);
    if(tree->left)
        printtree(tree->left);
    if(tree->right)
        printtree(tree->right);
}
int yyerror()
{
    printf("ERROR\n");
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Tell me something: why do you write YOUR ENTIRE GRAMMAR IN ALL-CAPS? If you were told to do so, I'd love to have a way to communicate with whoever gave you that ridiculous advice.

Comment: Also: that was not the only error produced by bison/yacc. You need to show all of them, nicely formatted, since many if the other ones actually explain what you did wrong.

Comment: The problem is that i cannot see my other problem because of this fatal error that i don't know how to fix

Comment: and for the ALL-CAPS, i learned it that way, but i modified it

Comment: `args` is unproductive because it has no non-recursive production. So Bison removes it, and also all productions which refer to it. That makes other non-terminals unproductive, so they get removed, too. Eventually it discovers that the start symbol is unproductive, so it stops. All of this is noted in the other error messages which come before the one you quote. You need to read all the error messages, not just the last one  (Usually the first one is the most important.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Reachability,_productiveness,_nullability

Comment: Ok i get it, thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause of the crash:

- you call `mknode` in a couple of places (eg, the block rule) with NULL as the first argument, but `mknode` calls strcpy with this argument as the source string, so it will crash

Other problems:

- you use `sizeof(token)` where token is a `char *` (getting the size of a pointer, not the length of the string.  You need `strlen(token)`.  Better yet, use `strdup(token)` to do the malloc+strcpy all in one.
- your grammar is inflexible, with almost-dupliacted rules and limited nesting. You're better off using fewer rules -- get rid of all the calc/expr stuff and just have

  ```
    expr: expr '+' expr
        | expr '*' expr
        | expr '<' expr
        | expr '>' expr
        | expr '=' expr
        | ID
        | NUM
        | '(' expr ')'
  ```

  and set precedence of your operators appropriately.  Similarly `block` and `body` should be combined into one non-terminal and a couple of rules.